# Why on Microsoft SQL Server am I getting error 10054 when I try to connect or just run my code from Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I have a project in Visual Studio that I've been working on that uses Microsoft SQL Server and it's been working fine until now. For some reason now when I try running the solution from Visual Studio it throws exceptions. When I go to SQL Server Management Studio to check it out, I can't connect to it. I get the following message when I press connect:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
> pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Is it a problem with something in Visual Studio solution or is it a problem with SQL Server, or is it something else entirely? Can someone please help me get it working again?

I already tried resyncing and rebuilding my branch of the project multiple times and it made no difference.
I tried following the directives on the Microsoft troubleshooting pages for SQL Server.
I also looked around the internet for help, but I haven't been able to find anything that could explain to me in an easy to understand way how to solve whatever the issue is.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-exist-connection-closed might help

Comment: Both programs have previously been working successfully with the same SQL Server instance and have just stopped working at the same time? I'd be suspecting that it's an old SQL Server instance (SQL Server 2014 or earlier) that doesn't have [TLS 1.2 updates applied and enabled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe) and your sys admins have just rolled out a patch or policy update to your own computer that has disabled the TLS 1.0 and 1.1 client protocol versions.

Comment: I don't think it's anything like that because I don't have any sys admin stuff on my computer.